# How to harmonically compose django webapps?

Tags: django, django-models, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates, django-views

Django's philosophy is about webapps being reusable. But how to achieve template harmony between different webapps?

Here is a hypothetical example: I want to resuse webapp 1 (e.g., [django_openid](https://github.com/simonw/django-openid/tree/master/django_openid/templates/django_openid)) for OpenID enabled sign-on; and I want to reuse webapp 2 (e.g., [django invitation app](https://github.com/eldarion/kaleo/tree/master/kaleo)) for customer invitation; and I want to write my own app (MTV) for statistics

But their templates normally do not look belonging to a single project. How can I reuse the existing work (web app 1 and web app 2 in above hypothetical example) with least intrusive work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that by 'intrusive', you mean editing files within the reusable app.

Without being intrusive at all, you should be able to override any templates in a reusable app, by placing them in a project-level templates directory, or by providing a template with a matching name in an app of your own.

Django template loading is completely configurable, but by default, it will look first in the directory named in settings as `TEMPLATE_DIRS`, and then in a `templates` directory in each of your installed apps, in the order they appear. By placing your app before openid or invitation in INSTALLED_APPS, then your custom templates will be loaded instead of the supplied ones.

In some cases, I have created an "app" for a project, which is actually just an empty models.py and a collection of templates. Then I have a place to store the site base templates, as well as all of the overridden templates from other apps.

Comment: why an empty app for that? You have mentioned TEMPLATE_DIRS... the directory would be sufficient IMO :)

Answer (score 1):

The `django invitation app`, like most reusable apps, has documentation with a [usage](http://kaleo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html) section. This will explain how you can reuse the app in your project.

`django_openid` appears to be "not ready yet" according to the readme, so you would need to dive in to the code a bit to use it.

In general, you will want to go to the documentation of the app you are attempting to reuse and look for a usage/implementation section.